# Pika RabbitMQ Error: Stream connection lost: ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by a remote host' )

Tags: python, rabbitmq, queue, pika

I am trying to run a worker model where I have single program sender.py that sends youtube urls and an index into a queue called the process_queue. Then I have defined a worker program called reciever.py that consumes from this process_queue and it runs a model and puts the json output to another queue called product_queue.

sender.py

```
import pika
import json
import time

messages=[
    {
        "url":'',
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "url": '',
        "id": 2
    }
]

connection=pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters(host='localhost'))
channel=connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='process_queue', durable=True)
channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)

for message in messages:
    
    messageJson=json.dumps(message)

    channel.basic_publish(
        exchange='',
        routing_key='process_queue',
        body=messageJson,
    )
    print(f'Sent: {message["id"]}')

connection.close()
```

reciever.py

```
import pika
import sys
import os
import json
from model import youtubeProducts

def main():
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost', heartbeat=60))
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.queue_declare(queue='process_queue',durable=True)

    channel.queue_declare(queue='product_queue',durable=True)

    def callback(ch, method, properties, body):
        message = json.loads(body)
        youtube_url = message['url']
        index=message['id']
        print(f'Recieved: {index}')

        prodList=youtubeProducts(youtube_url, index).run()
        
        ch.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='product_queue', body=prodList)

        ch.basic_ack(delivery_tag=method.delivery_tag)

    channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
    channel.basic_consume(queue='process_queue', on_message_callback=callback)

    channel.start_consuming()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Interrupted')
        try:
            sys.exit(0)
        except SystemExit:
            os._exit(0)
```

I encounter this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "reciever.py", line 34, in <module>
    main()
  File "reciever.py", line 30, in main
    channel.start_consuming()
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 1883, in start_consuming
    self._process_data_events(time_limit=None)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 2044, in _process_data_events
    self.connection.process_data_events(time_limit=time_limit)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 851, in process_data_events
    self._dispatch_channel_events()
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 567, in _dispatch_channel_events
    impl_channel._get_cookie()._dispatch_events()
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 1510, in _dispatch_events
    consumer_info.on_message_callback(self, evt.method,
  File "reciever.py", line 23, in callback
    ch.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='product_queue', body=prodList)
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 2265, in basic_publish
    self._flush_output()
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 1353, in _flush_output
    self._connection._flush_output(lambda: self.is_closed, *waiters)   
  File "C:\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pika\adapters\blocking_connection.py", line 523, in _flush_output
    raise self._closed_result.value.error
pika.exceptions.StreamLostError: Stream connection lost: ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None)
```

Anyone knows how to resolve this?

The problem seems to be arising from the channel.start_consuming(). The model returns a json object if I replace it with a print statement, it prints the correct values. Nothing gets put in the product queue also.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create two channel, one for the basic_consume and another for the basic_publish. [AMQP standard](https://www.amqp.org/sites/amqp.org/files/amqp.pdf) states that channels are unidirectional.